# How would you encode a Map<String, Object> using Protocol Buffers?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, amqp

I'm trying to use [Protocol Buffers](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fprotobuf%2F&ei=jrBVStaVC5vcmgO9m93dCQ&usg=AFQjCNEH5XQOuk2HkPhnqqJRXpNgRAOWdQ&sig2=UttuiLusS0zx5cbmEYa76w) for message serialization.

My message format should contain Map< String, Object > entries ... but how do I write the .proto definition?

As far as I know, Protocol Buffers does not have a build-in Map type. I could model around that using repeating fields. But the big problem I have is, that you need to define all your types. I want my message to be flexible, so I can't specify the types.

Any ideas?

Comment: For what it's worth: it now appears 'proto3' has `maps<,>` syntax: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#maps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd model a tuple with a key and a value (probably one value field per type that the value could be). Then just have a repeated list of that tuple type. You'd need to build the map itself in code.

When you say you can't specify the types - what sort of types are you talking about? If you have an optional field of each type in the tuple, then that would cope for all the primitives - and you *could* map messages by serializing them into a byte string.

It sounds like the level of "unstructure" you have may not be a good fit for PB though.

Comment: sounds reasonable ... but I guess you are right: PB does not look like a good fit for my problem

Comment: @artuh - what did you eventually used for your problem?

Comment: @FranzéJr.: Given that you haven't given any different requirements, why would you expect different information? Protocol buffers now support the concept of a map, but not to "generic message" - it has to be to a specific type.

Comment: @Jon Skeet 
The way to do this in Protobuf 3 now is to use their Struct well-known type: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Struct

This would be the "better" way to do this today and is effectively what you described in your answer.

Comment: @PragmaticProgrammer: `Struct` is good for modelling JSON, because that's what it's *specifically* for. Another option is `Any`, if every value is actually another protobuf message. (And of course, protobuf now does have maps...)