# Java HashMap in protocol buffer

Tags: java, protobuf-net

I am new to the Google protocol buffer. The intention is to use proto files to generate Java classes that can be sent over the network. Is there a way to have Java Maps in the generated classes? Any example code for it will be extremely useful. The generated Java class should contain a member variable of type `Map` of keys and values.

Comment: No, not in the current version.

Comment: Thanks for the version. Idea on when it will be available?

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue, regarding this in google https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/detail?id=299

The last message from *October 9, 2014*

> Project Member #4 xiaof...@google.com A new syntax for map fields will
>   be introduced to protobuf: message TestMessage {   map
>   a_map_field = 1; }
>
> We are currently working on its implementation and it's supposed to be
>   included in the next major release.

So either wait for new release, or implement your own tuples, with appropriate key and value structures.

Look at similar question
[How would you encode a Map<String, Object> using Protocol Buffers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102900/how-would-you-encode-a-mapstring-object-using-protocol-buffers)

Answer (score 0):

To folks visiting this page looking on how to add `Map` into protocol buffers. In proto version 3, [`map`](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#maps) has been added and you can use it as demonstrated below:

**The `Koltin` class:**

```
data class Person(
    val name : String,
    val badges : Map<String, String>
)
```

**The `.proto` file:**

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Person {
  string name = 1;
  map<string, string> badges = 2;
}
```